# How to set External File path in laravel layout

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel

I have one layout file called admin in which i have some external files addes like

below this files are in public directory

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/plugins.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/main.js"></script>
```

Now i have two view one post and other is allpost

and route for each layout is like this

**/posts**   for post view

**/posts/1**  for allposts view

Now when i load frst view everything workd fine it loads all the external dependancies

http://Myserver.com/plugins/jquery.js 
path for local file is correct

but when i load second view which is for particular post whith post id
it can't load external files because it requires different path to load files like

http://Myserver.com/posts/plugins/jquery.js"

so how can i solve this problem so i can use same layout for both view.

thanks in advance, really appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try add root slash in the beginning of js url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: this worked for me, however i'd like to know whether this is the best practice. looks more like a workaround to me.